# Why does my data card not work with USB-hub for 2G network

Tags: 3g, dongle, usb-hub

My data card works fine with 3G networks.

My laptop has only two USB ports and both are too close to connect a wide data card and a hub for mouse and keyboard.

As for the make/build:

- Windows 7
- Vodafone network
- ZTE

Why does my data card not work with USB-hub for 2G network?

Comment: Pop, you might want to clarify what your question is. At this point, you have only made a statement. What have you tried? Brand and model of laptop? Brand and model of the card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess would be a power issue.  Each successive data standard seems to use less power.  The most common issue when working through a hub is power related.  It seems likely this may be related.

One way to test is to get a powered hub and try it in 2G mode through the powered hub.

Comment: I agree - plug power into the Hub. But I also disagree. Because 3G uses more power than 2g(gprs).. so pop says 3g works not 2g? Odd